# angularjs redirection not picking window.local storage value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have used local storage. When i logged in  page redirect to myprofile page its not loading local storage value properly. Here i am getting null value. Once i reloaded then its getting local storage proper value how can i fix this.

```js
   .controller('SignInCtrl', ['$scope','$http' ,'$location','$window',
function($scope,$http, $location,$window) ]
 { 
  $scope.signin = function() 
   { 
       $http.post('***', userdetails).success(function(data,response) 
        {
      var nameResponse = JSON.stringify(data.Name); 
      window.localStorage.setItem("name",nameResponse);
      $location.path('/myprofile');  
        })
        
            }

     }])
     
.controller('MyprofileCtrl', ['$scope','$http' ,'$location','$window', 
function($scope,$http, $location,$window) 
 {
  var name=$window.localStorage.getItem("name");
     //console.log(name);
     if(name == null)
     {
      
      $scope.loginstatus ="Sign Up With Us";
      console.log($scope.loginstatus);
     }else
     {
      $scope.loginstatus ='Welcome '+ name.replace(/\"/g, "");
      console.log($scope.loginstatus);
     }
    }])
```

[image]

Comment: format your code, and you might consider using ng-storage https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Answer (score 0):

First of all you forgot to use `$window` instead of window

`window.localStorage.setItem("name",nameResponse);`

Should be

`$window.localStorage.setItem("name",nameResponse);`

I would expect your code to still work since window is in the global scope, but certain build processes could prevent it from working.

Also, you shouldn't stringify a string (`JSON.stringify(data.Name)`).

Comment: i have changed $window still i am getting null value but i checked my localstorage set item working properly.only getitem getting null value

Comment: When you type `window.localStorage` in your console, do you see the item you set? Are you REALLY sure you are not setting it to null?

Comment: please cheack i have enclosed my localstorage image

Comment: Try to run this in your console then `window.localStorage.getItem('name')`, what do you get?

Comment: null value .but value is stored in localstorage i have inserted image cheack